# I have the following firebase database and i am not able to retrieve the details like name,address,no

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

The following is an image from firebase database and i am not able to retrieve the data.

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
    // This method is called once with the initial value and again
    // whenever data at this location is updated.

    FirebaseData pg=dataSnapshot.getValue(FirebaseData.class);
    Log.d(TAG, "Value is: " + value);
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,value,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**FirebaseData.java class**

```
public class FirebaseData {
    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String pgid;
    public String contact_no;

    public FirebaseData() {
        // Needed for Firebase
    }

    public FirebaseData(String address, String name, String contact_no) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.contact_no=contact_no;
    }
```

Comment: Which data you want to get? From all localities or from a single one?

Comment: May be u need to use onDataChange() method ?

Comment: Can you post one more line from your code, I would like to see the line above @Override

Comment: @AlexMamo the address,contact_no and name from the parent "1"

Comment: There is a parent "1" in both nodes, HSRLayout and tinfactory. From which one? Or you want from both?

Comment: This is event listener i am using                                 myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override

Comment: @AlexMamo In this case from HSR Layout i want the fields  address,contact_no and name

Comment: `onChildChanged` will only fire when you make a change to a node. But it's hard to say where you're going wrong without seeing the [**minimal complete** code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). E.g. make sure to show how you attach the listener and to what location in the JSON you attach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `address`, `contact_no` and the `name` from `HSRLayout` node please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference HSRLayoutRef = rootRef.child("cities").child("Bangalore").child("localities").child("HSRLayout");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String address = dataSnapshot.child("1").child("address").getValue(String.class);
        String contact_no = dataSnapshot.child("1").child("contact_no").getValue(String.class);
        String name = dataSnapshot.child("1").child("name").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", address + " / " + contact_no + " / " + name);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
HSRLayoutRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Your output will be:

```
das / 15615446484 / HSR
```

If you want to get the data from multiple childs, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference HSRLayoutRef = rootRef.child("cities").child("Bangalore").child("localities").child("HSRLayout");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String address = ds.child("address").getValue(String.class);
            String contact_no = ds.child("contact_no").getValue(String.class);
            String name = ds.child("name").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", address + " / " + contact_no + " / " + name);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
HSRLayoutRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: this works for a single child i.e 1 butt if  it has multiple childs like "1","2","3",4... then how can i simplify the results

Comment: Yes, that's correct. But said you need for a single child. I have added new code that allows you to get data from multiple childs. Please see my updated answer. Is now everything alright?

Comment: if i want to bind  the results to view Holder how can we achieve this.....bcoz i tried calling a function from onDataChange method but its not calling any function neither able to add reults using result.add(new FirebaseData(address,contact_no,name));

Comment: Is not calling because onDataChange is asynchronous. There are good explicantions on this site regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In Database check Rules and set

```
{ "rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true}}
```